# AWS Lambda : CodePipeline job never ends, even after retuning sucess

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-codepipeline

I am working on executing an AWS Lambda code from Code-pipeline. I have given the lambda role full access to EC2 and code-deploy. The commands generally work when I am not triggering them from code-pipeline. When Triggered from code-pipeline, they just keep on running, even though success is sent. What am i doing wrong?

Code :

```
import boto3
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    reservations = boto3.client('ec2').describe_instances()['Reservations']
    instances_list = []
    process_instance_list = []
    command = 'COMMAND TO EXECUTE ON SERVER'
    ssm = boto3.client('ssm')
    for res in reservations:
      instances = res['Instances']
      for inst in res['Instances']:
        for tag in inst['Tags']:
            #print("Tag value is {}".format(tag['Value']))
            if tag['Value']=='Ubuntu_Magento':
               print("{} {} {}".format(tag['Value'], inst['InstanceId'], inst['LaunchTime']))
               instances_list.append(inst)

    instances_list.sort(key=lambda x: x['LaunchTime'])
    instance_id = instances_list[0]['InstanceId']
    ssmresponse = ssm.send_command(InstanceIds=[instance_id], DocumentName='AWS-RunShellScript', Parameters= { 'commands': [command]}) 
    code_pipeline = boto3.client('codepipeline')
    job_id = event['CodePipeline.job']['id']
    code_pipeline.put_job_success_result(jobId=job_Id)
```

Comment: What does the Lambda log show? One guess based on your question is that you need to grant Lambda permission to call CodePipeline.

Answer (score 0):

Any lambda by default has lifespan of 15 mins only, after that it exits no matter what. I think it has something to do with the way you are trigger it.